# How to run the expo EAS Build correctly with the good keystore for Android?

Tags: android, expo

I hope someone can help me with this and thx by advance.
I'm trying to use the futur only method (EAS) for build my expo app, and i get an error.
I already publish the app on apple store and play store.
When i run the build with expo command and after publish everthing is okay.
When i run the build with EAS the build is okay but when i run the publish i have the error "The Android App Bundle was signed with the wrong key. Found: SHA1: ####### expected #######

I think there is something wrong with the keystore when the build is run with EAS ?

Someone to help ?

Thank you ;)